# SQL ROWNUMBER efficiency

Tags: sql, db2, row-number

I have a poorly performing SQL that uses the ROWNUMBER function for paging. The page size was earlier set to 5000 but has been changed to 100. In my testing in a lower environment, the response time went down from 7s to under 1s after this change.

However, since the query does not have too many filters, a full table scan will likely occur if, for example, the LAST_UPD_DT in the predicate was set to today.

So in this situation, would setting the ROWNUMBER to a much lower value help or make little difference?

There are around 2.5 million records in Production and around 5k in Test where I saw the response go down from 7s to under 1s.

The query utilizes an index that has the same columns as the predicates. There is currently no index on the ORIG_TIME column but will be added. The database is DB2.

Below is a trimmed down version of the query that retains the basic essence of the issue.

```
    SELECT  * 
    FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT  ROWNUMBER ( ) OVER ( 
        ORDER BY MEMBERS.ORIG_TIME ASC ), 
              MEMBERS.APP_ID, 
              MEMBERS.NAME
        FROM MEMBERS 
        WHERE 
            MEMBERS.LAST_UPD_DT <= ? AND 
            ( MEMBERS.STAT_CD = 'S' OR MEMBERS.CURR_STAT = 'D' ) 
        ORDER BY MEMBERS.ORIG_TIME ASC 
      ) 
      AS TEMP_ 
    WHERE ROWNUMBER_ <= 100  --used to be 5000
```

Any thoughts or assistance will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is the `last_upd_dt` field indexed?  If so, why do you think there would be a table scan?

Comment: @DanBracuk yes it is. Perhaps I am mistaken, but if the query returned a bulk of the records from the table, then would the optimizer not find it more efficient to perform a table scan rather than an index lookup followed by reading data from the table?

Comment: `ORDER BY MEMBERS.ORIG_TIME ASC` in the subselect is pointless; if you need that order put it after the outer select.

Comment: What do you do with the data? Do you fetch all or just the first 100 or 5000 rows? What does query plan (explain) look like?

Answer (score 0):

Add yours indexes and rectify your query like it:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM 
  ( 
    SELECT  ROWNUMBER ( ) OVER (ORDER BY MEMBERS.ORIG_TIME ASC ) as RANG, 
            MEMBERS.APP_ID, MEMBERS.NAME
    FROM MEMBERS 
    WHERE 
    MEMBERS.LAST_UPD_DT <= ? AND ( MEMBERS.STAT_CD = 'S' OR MEMBERS.CURR_STAT = 'D' ) 
  ) 
  AS TEMP
WHERE RANG between 1 AND 5000 -- Modify here your range
order by RANG
```